# CSS :hover and transform

Tags: html, css

I have this situation:

Html:

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

css:

```
.button { 
   position:absolute; 
   left:0; top:0; 
   transform: translateY(50px); 
}

.button:hover { 
   transform: scale(1.2); /* keep the original transform */
}
```

Is there a way on hover to add just scale transform and not overwrite the translate?

Comment: You are closing a `<div>` element with a `</button>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just combine the two transforms, like this:

```
transform: translateY(50px) scale(1.2);
```

### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vqhjLg1q/3/)

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.button:hover {
  transform: translateY(50px) scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">hello</button>
```

Comment: I have more buttons with different transforms, I want to be dynamic, not hard coded

Comment: may i know, is it possible <div class="button">hello</button>? Here didn't close <div> right? thanks

Comment: @saina - I fixed the OP's typo now

Comment: @Hiero, in that case, you may need to use positioning `top:50px` on the button instead of `translateY` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vqhjLg1q/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/up0Lo9vx/5/)**

CSS:

```
 .button {
    width:auto;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color:blue;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: translateY(50px) scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: translateY(50px) scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: translateY(50px) scale(1.2);
    transform: translateY(50px) scale(1.2);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button">test</button>
<button class="button">test</button>
<button class="button">test</button>
<button class="button">test</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes just keep the value which you do not want to change same on hover of that element.